# How to access control in NSToolbar?

Tags: swift, macos, nstoolbaritem

Using a segmented control as an NSToolbarItem. The IBAction method works fine, in that I can access the segment that was selected. And I was able to validate the control through a custom subclass like below.

```
class ToolbarOptions: NSToolbarItem {
    override func validate() {
        print("toolbar options validate")
    }
}
```

What I've not been able to do is access the control for other needs, such as resetting the selected segment when the options are chosen via a menu item rather than clicking the toolbar item. In iOS, I'd create an outlet by control-dragging the segmented control, but that doesn't create an outlet in the view controller in OS x, it seems. What's the best practice for accessing the control?

Also, from the subclass of NSToolbarItem, what's the proper way to access methods and properties of the view controller or document that might be needed to determine if the tool should be enabled or disabled?

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: So with further research, I'm guessing the answer to both parts of the question lies in connection bindings. This is a little bit different from iOS, but I'm trying to wrap my head around it.